# JAXB not generating field for redefined attribute

Tags: jaxb

I have an xsd that redefines a complex type to add a sequence:

```
<xs:redefine>
  <xs:complexType name="data-extension.type">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
      <xs:extension base="data-extension.type">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="strict"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
```

However when I generate the code for my xsd using JAXB, the DataExtensionType class does not has a field for the sequence.
Am I missing something in the xsd or the JAXB generation parameters?

**Edit:**
This is the generated Java:

```
/**
* <p>Java class for data-extension.type complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="data-extension.type">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="{http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns}data-extension.type">
 *       &lt;redefine>
 *         &lt;complexType name="data-extension.type">
 *           &lt;complexContent>
 *             &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *             &lt;/restriction>
 *           &lt;/complexContent>
 *         &lt;/complexType>
 *       &lt;/redefine>
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;any processContents='lax' maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "data-extension.type", namespace = "http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    DefaultType.class,
    DataType.class
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver", date = "2018-03-02T02:29:07+00:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.8-b130911.1802")
public class DataExtensionType
    extends OriginalDataExtensionType
{


}
```

The comment suggest the sequence was found during parsing.

I was expecting to see a `List<Object> any` (or similar) and its getter to be generated. The supper class has a contents field, but its type is `String`.

**Edit 2:**

```
The OriginalData class:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    DataExtensionType.class
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver", date = "2018-03-02T02:29:07+00:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.8-b130911.1802")
public class OriginalDataExtensionType {

    @XmlValue
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver", date = "2018-03-02T02:29:07+00:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.8-b130911.1802")
    protected String content;

    /**
     * 
     *       Extension mechanism for the content of <data> and <default>.
     *       The complex type data-extension.type is empty per default.
     *       Users may redefine this type in order to add content to 
     *       the complex types data.type and default.type which are 
     *       extensions of data-extension.type.
     *     
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver", date = "2018-03-02T02:29:07+00:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.8-b130911.1802")
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the content property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver", date = "2018-03-02T02:29:07+00:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.2.8-b130911.1802")
    public void setContent(String value) {
        this.content = value;
    }

}
```

At first I also expected that the `contents` field would be the sequence.

Comment: Please post what's generated.

Comment: And `OriginalDataExtensionType` please. The `any` field may be there.

Comment: What does the original `data-extension.type` look like?
My best guess so far is that the `@XmlValue`-property in the parent class somehow prohibits generation of the `any`-property. I saw this in some schemas but there normally was a comment about that.

Comment: This is actually quite a complex case and I won't be surprized if XJC can't handle it properly.